# A function $f$ that increases from 0 to 1 exponentially as $x$ increases from 0 to 1 linearly.

Tags: functions

I am looking for a function $f(x)\in\ [0,1]$ when $x\in[0,1]$.

f(x) increases **slowly initially** when x is small starting from 0 till 0.1 (should be configurable), and after this pre-configured value, it should increase **very fast** eventually approaching 1 when x reaches 1.

The function distribution should be continuous and there is no restriction on the differentiability.

Comment: Would $x^{10000}$ be good? Why/Why not?

Comment: Any restrictions on differentiability, etc.?

Comment: No restriction on differentiability? *begins stretching the appropriate piece of the Weierstrass function into place*

Comment: x^10000 will not solve the purpose as it abruptly increase very close to x=1 and will be a very small value till then which contradicts with the requirement in the question.

Comment: @Mori Your comment appears to me to support that it *does* meet the requirement. That is, you state it's very small  near $x=0$, and increases very fast near $x=1$. Could you clarify? If this increases "too fast" for "very fast" near $x=1$, you can also try, for instance, $x^{5000}$? Is this inappropriate for another reason?

Comment: @GBeau - I am sorry if I framed the question ambiguously. I have corrected it. The requirement is to increase slowly till a pre-configured value, 0.1 taken as an example in the question and after that value, it should increase faster. x^5000 will also face the same problem as there is no way to configure the point after which it should increase fast.

Comment: @Mori You sound like you want a [piecewise function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise).

Comment: I am not inclined towards that as I require a continuous function and I think some modification with exponentiation should do the trick. Isn't it?

Comment: @Mori Piecewise does not imply discontinuous.

Comment: A continuous piecewise function would be f(x) = 1/9 x if x $\le$ .9 and f(x) = 9x - 8 if x > .9.  Did I do that right f(0) = 0; f(.9) = 1/9 x .9 = .1 = 9 x .9 - 8 = 8.1 - 8 = .1; f(1) = 9 x 1 - 8 = 1.

Comment: Exponention would involve, if you want, f(.9) = .1  solve for log .1/log .9 = 21.8.  $f(x) = x^{21.8}$ will do very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = x^N$ such that $x^.9 = .1$ means solving $\log_{.9} .1 = \ln .1 / \ln .9 = 21.854345326782832562577351508747$ So $ f(x) = x^21.854345326782832562577351508747$ will do nicely.  For $0 < x < .9$ $f(x) \le .1$ For $.9 \le x \le 1$, $f(x)$ increases from .1 to 1 very quickly.

Or maybe I misunderstand what "increase slow, and then fast" means (which means not differentiable) so maybe a piecewise function.

$f(x) = x/9$ if $0 \le x \le .9$; $f(x) = 9x - 8.1$ if $x > .9$ Well increase slowly (1/9) until it reaches .1 and then it will increase quickly (9) and it's continuous.